# Celery SQS Consumer Issue: Visibility Timeout and Message Handling

Tags: python, celery

I've implemented a Celery SQS consumer application with a visibility timeout of 3600 seconds configured in the broker_transport_options. The consumer processes messages from an SQS queue produced by another microservice using the send_task method.

I'm facing two main issues:

1. *Visibility Timeout*: Despite setting the visibility timeout to 3600 seconds, the SQS message is moving from the "in-flight" state to the "available" state in just over a minute. The processing of the message takes more than 1 minute, and I expected the message to remain in the "in-flight" state during this time.
2. *Exception Handling*: When an exception occurs during message processing, the message is removed from the queue instead of being retried. I want the message to be retried in case of an exception.

Below are simplified versions of the relevant code:

producer.py

```py
import json
from celery import Celery


# Initialize a Celery app
app = Celery("my_app", broker="sqs://")

broker_transport_options = {
    "region": "ap-northeast-1",
    "predefined_queue_name": "sample_queue",
    "use_ssl": True,
    "polling_interval": 60,
    "visibility_timeout": 3600,
}
app.conf.update(broker_transport_options=broker_transport_options)


# Define a function to send a message to the Celery worker
def send_message(message: str, queue_name: str):
    # Use the queue_name to specify the target consumer
    result = app.send_task(
        "sqs_celery_app_factory.process_message", args=[message], queue=queue_name, retries=3
    )
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    json_str = {

        "request-id": "2",
        "tenant_id": "abc",
        "language": "en",
    }

    queue_name = "sample_queue"  # Specify the queue name for the desired consumer
    result = send_message(json.dumps(json_str), queue_name)
    print(f"Message sent to {queue_name}")
```

Consumer:

```py
# consumer.py
class SQSCeleryAppFactory(CeleryAppFactory):
    def create_celery_app(self, queue_name: str, processor: type) -> Celery:
        app = Celery(
            queue_name,
            broker="sqs://",
            backend="redis://",
            include=processor.__module__,
        )

        app.conf.update(
            result_expires="3600",
            task_serializer="json",
            accept_content="json",
            worker_prefetch_multiplier="1",
            task_acks_late="True",
        )

        broker_transport_options = {
            "region": "ap-northeast-1",
            "predefined_queue_name": queue_name,
            "use_ssl": True,
            "polling_interval": 60,
            "visibility_timeout": 3600,
        }
        app.conf.update(broker_transport_options=broker_transport_options)

        queue = Queue(queue_name)
        app.conf.update(
            task_queues=(queue,),
            task_default_queue=queue_name,
        )

        @shared_task
        def process_message(message: str):  # type: ignore
            return processor().process_message(message)

        return app
```

Processor.py

```py
#processor.py
class SQSConsumer(MessageProcessor):
    @shared_task
    def process_message(message: str):  # type: ignore
        print("Message: ", message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SQSCeleryAppFactory().create_celery_app("sample_queue", SQSConsumer)
    app.worker_main(
        argv=[
            "worker",
            "--loglevel",
            log_level,
            "--concurrency",
            concurrency,
            "--max-tasks-per-child",
            max_tasks_per_child,
            "-Q",
            "sample_queue",
        ]
    )
```

Could someone guide me on what I might be missing in the configuration to address these issues?